# why it shows me error on .toString() method

Tags: android, android-studio

```
myListViewForSong.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String songName = myListViewForSong.getItemIdAtPosition(position).toString();
         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class).putExtra("songs",mySongs).putExtra("songname",songName));
    }
});
```

Comment: In your code block "toString()" method is not there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert text into string.

```
     String songName =myListViewForSong.getItemIdAtPosition(position).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getItemIdAtPosition` will return `long` which is primitive, so you cannot do `toString()` on primitives, instead use `String.valueOf()`

```java
String songName = String.valueOf(myListViewForSong.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
```